# New blender 3.2 sculpt paint does not work

Tags: vertex-paint, sculpt-mode

iam testing the new blender 3.2 and somehow, the sculpt paint does nothing at all. On all the videos I watched, they just subdivide for enough resolution and go to the sculpting mode, select paint and starts painting. In my case, nothing happens. Is there a default setting that needs to be adjusted to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have selected attribute in shading:

[image]

If you want to make it visible in other shading modes (render and material preview), add *color attribute* node in the material setup:

[image]